# Intercept Sent text messages android

Tags: java, android

I'm creating a Text Encryption app, but I don't want to make a whole new text app, I just want it to handle the encryption/decryption. So I was wondering, is there a way I can somehow intercept text messages sent from an app, encrypt it, and then send it?

I know I can get the received messages, that's the easy part. But does anybody have any ideas how to get the sent messages BEFORE they are sent?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So I was wondering, is there a way I can somehow intercept text messages sent from an app, encrypt it, and then send it?

Fortunately, this is impossible, as it would be a massive security flaw.

Comment: Yea, that's what I was thinking. At least a guy can hope. Thanks.